# CRUD with Access Database using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How can I use Microsoft Access as a database in ASP.NET website? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it possible. You will have to use OLEDB to Access the MS Access Database.

```
Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

   Dim myPath As String
   myPath = Server.MapPath("Database1.mdb")

   con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=" & myPath & ";"
   Dim myCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand

   myCommand.CommandText = "insert into Students(Firstname,Lastname,Address) values('" & txtFirstname.Text & "','" & txtLastname.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "')"
   myCommand.Connection = con
   con.Open()
   myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   con.Close()
```

Taken from: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Connecting-Access-Sql-Server.aspx

It would be the same as SQL Server but you will be using OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand etc

Answer (score 3):

Sure, Access has an [oledb connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte(VS.71).aspx)

Now I would not recommend it unless its a toy app. But yes it can be done.

Comment: +1 Toy App - MS Access should not be used as a real database.

Comment: Does Office Access has to be running to access that database file?

Comment: No. It is NOT similar to SQL Server where a service should be running to access the DB. So MS Access does not have to be running to access the data :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is possible.

Checkout this tutorial.

http://aspalliance.com/429

This isn't online anymore:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Connecting-to-a-Microsoft-Access-database-with-ASPNET/

Answer (score 2):

**Yes it's possible, but NOT advisable!**

Access was never meant to be used in a highly concurrent environment like the web.
I don't know what type of site you are trying to create, but you're better
of with a real database like SQL Express [(Free download on Microsoft)](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)

Answer (score 0):

```
string strConn ="PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|referendum-abrogrativo.mdb";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);

try
{
    conn.Open();

    string query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = '" + email + "' AND Password = '" + password + "'";

    OleDbCommand cmdE = new OleDbCommand();
    cmdE.Connection = conn;
    cmdE.CommandText = query;

    OleDbDataReader dr;
    dr = cmdE.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        _IDUte = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        _Email = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
        _Password = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        _Email = "";
        _Password = "";
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```